# Freeform not sending notifications with custom template, default template works fine

Tags: solspace-freeform, ee

My Code is below. Works fine when using the default template,but it doesn't send with my custom.  I was also able to send emails from the cp without a problem....any suggestions???

-Using EE 2.8, Freeform 4.1.8

```
{exp:freeform:form form_id="1" form_name="contact" required="full_name|email|user_message" return="contact/index" template=“contact_used" admin_notify="Eric@nutmegit.com" admin_notification_template="contact_used" }
<div class="contact-form">
    <h3 class="widget-head-border colr">Quick Contact</h3>
    <div class="cont-form-in">
        <ul class="form-short">
            <li class="txt">
                <h5>Your Name</h5>
                <p>Required</p>
            </li>
            <li class="inputbar">
                <input type="text" name="full_name"/>
                <div class="inputicon"><img src="images/name-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="form-short">
            <li class="txt">
                <h5>Your Email</h5>
                <p>Required</p>
            </li>
            <li class="inputbar">
                <input type="text" name="email"/>
                <div class="inputicon"><img src="images/mail-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="form-short">
            <li class="txt">
                <h5>Your Organization or Business</h5>
            </li>
            <li class="inputbar">
                <input type="text" name="company_organization"/>
                <div class="inputicon"><img src="images/address.png" alt="" /></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="form-short">
            <li class="txt">
                <h5>Enter Message</h5>
                <p>Required</p>
            </li>
            <li class="textarea">
                <textarea rows="" cols="" name="user_message"></textarea>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="form-short">
            <li>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
{/exp:freeform:form}
```

Comment: Do you have notify_admin="yes" added to your freeform tag? Also: use proper <label> tags in your forms, it's accessibility 101.

Comment: Added notify_admin="yes", still not receiving the notifications.

Comment: Check which way around the admin_notify and notify_admin tags are. I *always* get it the wrong way around!